# How to create automatic new line?

Tags: regex, matlab

Can someone help me create an anonymous function `format_this(txt)` to format text so there's a newline character replacing a whitespace that is close to the edge of the command window - in essence 'pretty printing'? It does **not** have to be perfect (and in fact, doesn't **need** to be an anonymous function), however I couldn't find something like that oddly enough...

Here's what I have:

```
txt='the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
txt=[txt ' ' txt ' ' txt]; %make longer
w=getfield(get(0,'CommandWindowSize'),{1}); %command window width
space_pos=strfind(txt,' '); %find space positions
wrap_x_times= (w:w:size(txt,2))); %estimate of many times the text should wrap to a newline

format_this=@(txt) txt; 

%something like an ideal output:
disp(format_this(txt)) %example for super-small window
ans = 
   'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
   the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
   the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

Comment: I will post a solution if no answers, but since I had a hard time finding this, maybe the answer will be of use to others

Comment: @tripleee it's matlab, I didn't find a textwrap function, here's a longwinded function [link](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53176-wraptext). It's not homework, it's something that just annoyed me. I also like elegant code.

Comment: Sorry, missed the Matlab requirement.  Quick googling gets me https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53176-wraptext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a combination of string functions to achieve that result. The program below shows how to do that.

```
clc

% the text
txt='the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
% makethe text a bit longer
txt=[txt ' ' txt ' ' txt]; 
% get the command window width
w=getfield(get(0,'CommandWindowSize'),{1}); 
% get the length of the text
txt_len = numel(txt);

% check if the length of text is exactly divisible
% by the size of window (w) or not
if(mod(txt_len, w)~= 0)
    % if not, then get the number of
    % characters required to make it a
    % multiple of w
    diff_n = w - mod(txt_len, w);
    % append that many spaces to the end of the string
    txt(end+1 : end+diff_n) = ' ';
end

% create an anoymous function 
% step 1 - Split the array in multiple of size w into a cell array
%          using reshape() and cellstr() function respectively
% step 2 - concatenate the newline character \n at the end of each
%          element of the cell array using strcat()
% step 4 - join the cell array elements in a single string usin join()
format_this = @(txt)join(strcat(cellstr(reshape(txt,w, [])'), '\n'));
% get the formatted string as a 1-d cell array
formatted_str = format_this(txt);
% print the string to ft
ft = sprintf(formatted_str{1});
% display the ft
disp(ft)
```

Program Output tested with variable size of the command window.

[image]

[image: Larger Command Window]

[image]

Comment: You can take a couple of shortcuts in your code... There's no real need for the `if` statement, as something like `txt(end+1:end+0)` is empty, so will do nothing if there's no remainder. The anonymous function is a bit surplus as it requires the previous setup... unless you can do the whitespace padding inside the function, it might as well operate directly on `txt`. You can use `fprintf` instead of `sprintf` with `disp`. Your code does appear to work as desired though, these are just pointers for reference :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the facts. I am not as experienced like the experts here e.g., you. That's the reason I solve the problems here with basic long method some times. But gradually I will reach there to the expert level, I know. :)

Answer (score 2):

For printing in the Command Window, this is a preference which can be set in the preferences pane under

> HOME > Preferences > Command Window

[image: preferences]

The result can be seen with a quick test:

[image: test]